# ms excel compare text

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have 3 columns in excel, which contains text. I want to ask for a formula that can solve my problem. the situation is like this

```
a    b    c (result)

n    n    c
n    c    c
c    c    c
c    p    p
p    c    w
w    c    w
w    p    p
```

I need to compare the value of column `a` and `b`, then the result will be on column `c`.

Is there a way for to get the result above?

Comment: I can't decipher the rule for the column c results from those in a and b. Would you mind elaborating please?

Comment: even i, i'm having a hard time to decipher it... i'll come back when i understand it further

Comment: Do you know where the series originates? Genetics possibly?

Comment: -1 for not understanding your own question :).

Answer (score 0):

OK here we go. First thing, assign n = 3, p = 2, w = 1, c = 0. The trick here is to identify that the function range is then one less than the function domain. We are inspired then to use MOD(,3).

Your problem transforms thus:

```
a   b   c
3   3   0
3   0   0
0   0   0
0   2   2
2   0   1
1   0   1
1   2   2
```

The formula you can use in column c is `=MOD((B1*2+1)*(A1-B1)^2,3)`, copied down appropriately.

Recognising that 'x' with 'x' always gives 'c' has persuaded me to assign 0 to 'c', and, furthermore, use a subtraction in the formula. The squaring has the effect of pushing a number round the modulus and the final flourish is a linear multiplier of column B. (You can see what this does by expanding to a table):

```
    3   2   1   0
3   0   2   0   0
2   1   0   0   1
1   1   2   0   1
0   0   2   0   0
```

You then need to substitute for your original letters.

Comment: I don't understand that at all. Can you show me how to get to the result in the format that the OP asked, i.e a+b=c? It might clear my mind to the solution described. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the series you've provided is the full sequence . The following formula entered in Column C1 dragged down to C7 will give you the results you are looking for.

```
=IF(OR(A1=B1,A1="n"),"c",IF(B1="c","w","p"))
```